# "Два раза" — это словосочетание или нет?

Tags: синтаксис, словосочетания

**Два раза** — это словосочетание или нет?
Если нет, то какая конструкция?

Answer (score 4):

Это количественное словосочетание (с количественным числительным в роли главного слова).

> Особый случай - количественные числительные в составе словосочетаний. В словосочетаниях они обычно выступают в роли зависимых слов, однако не всегда. В именительном и винительном падежах такие числительные являются главным словом, в остальных пдежных формах - подчиненным. Сравните: «Двадцать лет проработал в охране» – «А вы, - перебил меня капитан, - служите Родине только до шести часов?!». В словосочетании до шести часов стоящее в форме родительного падежа числительное шесть является зависимым словом: до часов (скольких?) шести – это согласование. В словосочетании двадцать лет числительное двадцать является главным словом: двадцать (чего?) лет – это управление. 
>   (http://gramma.ru/EXM/?id=4.38)

Answer (score 2):

Это словосочетание, но не свободное, а цельное (слитное).

По степени спаянности компонентов словосочетания бывают:

1. Синтаксически свободные словосочетания — результат свободного объединения двух самостоятельных слов, каждое из которых обладает полноценным лексическим значением. В таких словосочетаниях главное слово является главным и грамматически, и по смыслу, а зависимое уточняет значение главного в том или ином отношении. Каждый из компонентов свободного словосочетания в предложении является **отдельным членом предложения**. Свободные словосочетания легко разлагаются на составные части: контрольная работа, задачник по математике, работать круглосуточно.
2. Синтаксически несвободные (цельные) словосочетания — это соединение слов, в котором грамматически зависимое слово является главным по смыслу, а грамматически главное слово является недостаточным с точки зрения семантики (информации). Синтаксически несвободные словосочетания не разлагаются на составные части. В предложении синтаксически цельные словосочетания **являются одним членом предложения**: два дома, несколько студентов, мало времени.

Модели несвободных (цельных) словосочетаний:

1. Количественно-именные словосочетания. 
   В них главное слово обозначает количество (число, объём, размер), но не имеет предметного значения, а зависимое — слово с предметным значением в родительном падеже: три карандаша, двое ребят, столько людей, много машин, множество книг.
2. Словосочетания со значением избирательности. 
   В них главное слово — местоимение или числительное, зависимое — существительное или местоимение в родительном падеже с предлогом «из»: один из нас, каждый из присутствующих, некоторые из учеников, кто-то из ребят.
3. Словосочетания с метафорическим значением.
   Главное слово употреблено в переносном значении и называет то, на что похож предмет, зависимое слово — прямое название предмета: серп месяца, шапка кудрей, зеркало реки, пламень уст (С. Есенин), листьев медь (С. Есенин), костёр рябины (С. Есенин).
4. Словосочетания со значением неопределённости.
   Главное слово — неопределённое местоимение, зависимое — согласуемое прилагательное, причастие: что-то неприятное, кто-то незнакомый, некто сидящий.
5. Словосочетания со значением совместности.
   Такие словосочетания называют равноправных участников совместного действия. Главное слово — существительное или местоимение в именительном падеже, зависимое — существительное в творительном падеже с предлогом «с»: брат с сестрой, Коля с товарищем, мы с приятелем. Словосочетания, построенные по такой модели, являются цельными только в роли подлежащего и только в том случае, если сказуемое стоит во множественном числе: мама с дочкой готовили обед; Николай с Денисом ходили в лес. Если подлежащее стоит в единственном числе, словосочетание является свободным: отец с сыном пошёл в зоопарк (подлежащее — отец, с сыном — дополнение).
6. Контекстуально-цельные словосочетания.
   Цельность их возникает только в контексте предложения или сложного словосочетания: умный человек сумеет разобраться в этом; девушка с голубыми глазами, человек высокого роста.
7. Словосочетания в составных сказуемых, включающие в себя вспомогательные глаголы, глаголы-связки или другие вспомогательные компоненты: Он начал рассказывать о приключениях в джунглях Амазонки; Мы хотим вам помочь; Она выглядела усталой.